# Cannot change file type in Linux version

Tags: c++, qt

Changing the file type only works for Windows but does not work in Linux. In Linux it does not change the file type.

```
QRegExp pattern("\\b(stl)\\b", Qt::CaseInsensitive);
if (info.suffix().isEmpty()) {
    filename += QLatin1String(".") + "stl";
}
else if (!pattern.exactMatch(info.suffix())) {
    filename += QLatin1String(".") + "stl";
}
```

The filetype displays "plain text document (text/plain)" instead of stl ([STereoLithography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)) potentially).

Comment: you use this code for what? I just wonder, because it does not compile

Comment: @Noooobz2016 I changed the formatting and question to what I think you are trying to ask. If this is not what you are asking then please revert the edit. I did this because the question was being flagged as "unclear what your are asking".

Comment: @Floris Velleman thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from you code, you just try to change file extension. This may work on Windows. But Linux doesn't use file extension for file type determination. Linux checking file content for this.

Comment: thanks, you're right. Is there any ways to change file type in Linux?

Comment: Put valid content inside file. This is the only way.

Comment: can you give an example to create a valid content for this.

Comment: Open link to wikipedia from your question. There are some examples of this files content.